# How to connect to a telnet service by bash?

Tags: bash, telnet

What I am trying to do is connect through telnet and download a database but I can't find the way to do it, I have tried it with python but it only closes the connections, so I would like to know if there is a way to do it with a bash script

Of course, what happens is that it is an entry checker, the only way to connect to it is through telnet, I know it is not the best but it is what it is.

I managed to make the connection through the expect interpreter, now I just move on the device to execute this command

this is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set name 192.168.1.169
set user "root"
set passwd  "solokey"

spawn telnet $name
expect "ZMM100 login: "
send "$user\r"
expect "Password: "
send "$passwd\r"
expect "#"
send "cd /mnt/mtdblock/data/ \r"
expect "#"
send "rm -rf ZKDB.db.bak \r"
expect "#"
send "cp ZKDB.db ZKDB.db.bak \r"
expect "#"
send "cat ZKDB.db.bak | nc -l -p 6666 \r"
expect "#"
```

Comment: telnet's not a very good file transfer protocol; perhaps you could explain the environment a bit more?

Comment: ready, you can check the edition

Comment: Telnet has its own protocol, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854 and does NOT include file transfer functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that telnet is not a transfer service, but it was the only option to be able to access the data, I leave the code in case it works for someone, in this way access through telnet to a biometric checker and we downloaded its database

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set name 192.168.1.169
set user "root"
set passwd  "solokey"

spawn telnet $name
expect "ZMM100 login: "
send "$user\r"
expect "Password: "
send "$passwd\r"
expect "#"
send "cd /mnt/mtdblock/data/ \r"
expect "#"
send "rm -rf ZKDB.db.bak \r"
expect "#"
send "cp ZKDB.db ZKDB.db.bak \r"
expect "#"
send "cat ZKDB.db.bak | nc -l -p 6666 \r"
expect "#"
```

already only on the client side, we execute

```
nc 192.168.1.169 6666 <ZKDB.db.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

Telnet is a remote commands executor and will not suit you as an FTP client.

What you can do is make **netcat** listen on a local port then telnet to the remote host and use netcat to stream the remote file on the local port and redirect the output to the local file.

On your local host :

```
nc -l -p <port> > <output_file>
```

On your remote machine, use telnet to execute this command :

```
nc -w 3 <local_host_ip> <port>  < <input_file>
```

Also, since you are not able to use ssh, ftp, you can expose an http server ( Using python SimpleHTTPServer if it's installed) or any http server on the remote server then use wget to download your files.

On the remote host :

```
cd <to_the_directory_to_expose>
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

On the local machine :

```
wget http://<remote_host_ip>:8000/<filename>
```